# MariaDB FATAL ERROR: Upgrade Failed

Tags: mariadb

I'm managing a SeaFile instance where I'm encountering a weird set of log messages on MariaDB start. Here is what `systemctl status mysql` spits out:

[image: systemctl status]

I don't know what that is. MariaDB says Upgrade failed. I did not ask for any upgrades. MariaDB says Access denied for user root@localhost. I can run `sudo mysql -u root` which results in a welcome message, but the console input line starts with `MariaDB [(none)]>` I also do not know what that is or means.

I can't find any information on these error logs, especially about the Upgrade message.

UPDATE: I have followed instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382478/2645815). Now the server doesn't start at all, and falls over with [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/812719/mysql-mariadb-not-starting) error.

Comment: Welcome, it would be so much better if you posted text information as text instead of an image.

Comment: Perhaps you had the wrong password for MariaDB's :root: user?

Comment: No, the error clarifies that the login attempt was `PASSWORD: NO`. Meaning the attempt was not by using password but by some other means. I don't really understand it and can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just ran into this issue after what turned out to be 2 unfortunate events.

I did a minor MariaDB upgrade, which restarted the server. Unfortunately, the server crashed during shutdown, and the upgrade script, which on OpenSUSE is `ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper  upgrade` tried to run `mysql_upgrade` which in turn crashed because some of the tables were corrupted and Innodb recovery hasn't run yet. Because of this `ExecStartPre` step failure, the start script never got to starting the actual Mariadb (`ExecStart=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper     start`).

What I did to fix it:

1. Start MariaDB directly, bypassing the upgrade step: `/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper start`. The server started fine and performed a recovery step:

```
2023-05-22 11:41:25 0 [Note] mysqld: Aria engine: starting recovery
recovered pages: 0% 10% 20% 38% 50% 60% 70% 80% 90% 100% (0.0 seconds); tables to flush: 4 3 2 1 0
 (0.0 seconds);
2023-05-22 11:41:25 0 [Note] mysqld: Aria engine: recovery done
```

2. At this point, `mysql_upgrade` or `/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper upgrade` complete OK and don't crash.
3. Done. I checked with `rcmysql restart` and the server restarted OK. The issue is now solved.

I think the MariaDB/MySQL teams can definitely optimize for this case and try to trigger an automatic repair during upgrade if it's needed.

Hope this helps someone.